# How was The Sopranos title sequence changed after September 11th, 2001?

Tags: production, credits, the-sopranos, title-sequence

*The Sopranos* [original title sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJpNmYeooQE) featured a prominent view of Lower Manhattan and the World Trade Center reflected in the passenger mirror of Tony Soprano's [Chevrolet Suburban](https://www.imcdb.org/v026373.html).

The accompanying title credited [Lorraine Bracco](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000966/) as Dr. Jennifer Melfi.

[image: Lorraine Bracco title credit over the World Trade Center]

Was this shot removed from the opening credits following the 9/11 terrorist attacks? If so, how were the scenes modified?

Have the creators of the show and/or the title sequence commented on the Twin Towers' presence in the opening credits following their destruction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That shot is there in Season 3, broadcast early 2001.

By season 4 in 2002 it is replaced by two very generic scenery shots, which remained until the very last episode.

[image]

[image]

As to whether anyone commented on it, I don't know, but there was more than enough to occupy people's thoughts without production needing to come up with an explanation for its removal.